# Disable Network Permission for all Flatpaks

Tags: networking, firewall, flatpak

The [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) Flatpak has a toggle to disable network permissions (`share=network`) for all Flatpaks installed on your system. How can I do this same thing by command line, for all Flatpaks installed on my system?